# How does an Apple device gets recognized as external storage on PC?

Tags: authentication, car-integration

When I connect any apple device to my PC - it gets recognized as an external storage and I can access all the files (Update:Not all the files - but just pictures) on the device.

How is this possible? Do all the laptops and desktop motherboards come with an Apple authentication chip and drivers ?

I am working on a device which needs to read music files from Apple devices - so I am wondering whether I need to apply for MFI program. If the apple devices work as generic USB device without any chip and special drivers, then it serves my purpose.

Comment: It works like a USB device.

Comment: That implies that I don't need to join the MFI program? So I wonder, that there are so many devices especially car head units which are MFI enabled - why did they go for the MFI if all they need is to scan the music and be able to play the files like a normal USB drive is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone will present itself as a digital camera to a USB host so you can use camera software to import photos, such as iPhoto.